# How to see which contacts aren't in a group?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, contacts, google-contacts

In Google Contacts/Gmail you can assign a contact to a group (or more than one group). I use this so that on my Android phone I can filter the list of contacts down to just work colleagues, just family, just people I know through a hobby or sport, etc.

I'm pretty disciplined about always adding people into a group when I add them through the web interface at a PC, but I often forget if someone gives me their phone number when I'm out-and-about, for instance.

I can filter the list of contacts in the web interface by clicking the group name to see people in that group, but there doesn't seem to be any way to filter to just see people who aren't in any groups?

Mine is a Google Apps account, in case it matters, but I'd be happy with an answer that only works on the main Gmail on the basis that these features come to Apps accounts eventually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the old version of contacts, in the list of contacts you can see what groups they're each in on the right hand side:

[image: t]

Contacts that are in no groups show an empty space.

<sub>Disclaimer: this is how it appears in my normal Gmail account.</sub>

Comment: Do you mean clicking the Contacts link that appears below all your mail labels? When I click that I see my full list of contacts, but to the right-hand side of them are the "View Suggestions" and "Find Duplicates" button, I can't seem to make your view show. Do you have any likely Labs turned on? Disclaimer, I am looking at a Google Apps account, so it could be this has changed in newer versions of GMail. I do have an unused, dummy normal GMail account that I'll check this on later when I can find the password.

Comment: @GAThrawn: I've updated my answer to show where the contacts link is.

Comment: Thanks, have logged into my unused normal GMail account, and everything works as you described. On the basis that these changes will eventually make it all the way to my main Google Apps Gmail, I'm happy to accept this as the answer.

Comment: Just to add an update to this answer, if you click on the contacts and you are taken to the new Contact preview you can *return to the old style* by clicking on the **More** option on the left and then clicking on **Leave the Contacts preview**.

Comment: Old answer... Now "contacts" calls contacts.google.com...