# Searching for Google contacts not in Groups

Tags: google, google-contacts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Google Contacts - how to see which contacts aren't in a group?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/6088/google-contacts-how-to-see-which-contacts-arent-in-a-group)

In Google Contacts, I've had Groups set up which look like this: `All Contacts`.. `Family`.. `School`.. `Work`.. etc.

Each contact I have is assigned to `All Contacts`. In addition, it is assigned to at least one more Group.

Sometimes when I add contacts, I forgot to bucket them in the respective groups, so I was wondering is there anyway I could do a search for `contact that belongs to`All Contact`-group, but does not belong to any other group` ?

Comment: @AlEverett shouldn't there be a way not to do this manually ?

Comment: Perhaps, but that's a question better asked of the Google developers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Custom way :**

In Contacts, click Export and save your contacts to as "Outlook CSV" formatted file on your computer.

Open that file, which by default is named contacts.csv, in a spreadsheet.  There is a column called Group Membership that contains the groups associated with each contact.

It's easy to filter those in a spreadsheet to find contacts without groups. Hope this helps you out.

Comment: what do you mean by open "in a spreadsheet" ? excel can't read the file..

Comment: You've to open it in Google Docs bro!

Comment: Excel certainly _can_ read CSV files.

Comment: @AlEverett oh yes excel can read outlook csv but not google csv.

Comment: CSV is just a text file with fields separated by commas. You may have to tweak the import settings a bit but that's not unusual.